# Does Google use AJAX powered hash fragment links in sitelinks?

Tags: google, links, sitelinks

On my website, I use anchor tags to navigate as it's a single page. With that in mind, my links for the main nav look like:

- `https://www.example.com#about`
- `https://www.example.com#contact`
- `https://www.example.com#pricing`

It's my hope that Google will see this navigation and build the sitelinks on my search listing from them but if they don't count as internal links then I don't think this will happen.

Could someone clarify, do they count as internal links or should I split the site into separate pages?

Comment: I guess instead of using "#" sign in a link, you should use slash "/" sign in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not index hashtag links. I wish they would though. I believe it would be a useful feature. If you run a Google search for "wikipedia cat", you'll see that Google does not index urls like wikipedia.org/cat#behavior and wikipedia.org/cat#biology

In order to have Google understand your page better and index these hashtag URLs, it is advised that you use rich structured data and html schema markup. Here are some examples to get you started:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-content
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data

Comment: Google does sometimes use hashtag links.   Here is a query for "wikipedia cat biology" where Google includes a "jump to biology" link in the search results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM9oF.png   I have never seen Google use the hashtag links for sitelinks though.

Answer (score 2):

I very doubt if it will be the case. Url parts after hashbang aren't transferred through server.

If i guess right, and your site is a onepager, so i get much more doubts about Google would establish sitelinks:(

But, if your site is not a onepager, you could easy change this behavior and get much higher chances to achieve your goal:

- address your menu entries with parameter instead of hashbang, like `?m=about`.
- establish internal links to them from other pages, not from the startpage.